Automatically add ldap-users to docker-group on Ubuntu 24.04
Many of our students log into our lab-computers (running Ubuntu 24.04) via LDAP. This works perfectly.
I've also edited /etc/adduser.conf regarding EXTRA_GROUPS and ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS, so that every newly created ldap-user is added to the docker group on each system. But this does not work.
How can you automatically add each new ldap-user to the docker group on Ubuntu?

Do you also manage groups with LDAP? If so, have you tried creating a docker group in LDAP? Or maybe pam_group would work.

This question is similar to: OpenLDAP/SSSD Automatically Add User to Local Group. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, I don't manage groups with LDAP.
Thanks for that link. I already tried this and it broke my login-screen. I could not log into my system and had to redo that pam group changes via root shell. Very frustrating.
